# incorrect output using re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

Problem statement:

> Inserts an extra space after a period if the period is directly followed by a letter.

Below is code:

```
string="This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!"

re.sub("\.[a-zA-Z]", ". ", string)
```

and output:

```
"This is very funny and cool. ndeed!"
```

It is replacing the first character after `'.'`.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Try using a capturing group

Answer (score 3):

You can use [positivie lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which does not consume the matched part:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\.(?=[a-zA-Z])", ". ", string)
'This   is  very funny  and    cool. Indeed!'
```

Alternative using [capturing group and backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
>>> re.sub(r"\.([a-zA-Z])", r". \1", string)  # NOTE - r"raw string literal"
'This   is  very funny  and    cool. Indeed!'
```

FYI, you can use `\S` instead of [a-zA-Z] to match non-space characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use both [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> string="This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\.)(?=[A-Za-z])', r' ', string)
'This   is  very funny  and    cool. Indeed!'
```

OR

You may  use [`\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html),

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\.)\b(?=[A-Za-z])', r' ', string)
'This   is  very funny  and    cool. Indeed!'
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\.)` Just look after to a literal dot.
- `(?=[A-Za-z])` Asserts that the matched boundary must be followed by a letter.
- If yes, then replace the boundary with space.